# C++: "Inferring" template type from a dependent type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class:

```
class MyClass{
    enum Choices : int
    {
        First,
        Last
    };
    template<MyClass::Choices choice>
    void bar(...);
};
```

I want to be able to make a `choice`-templated call to `bar()` in the client code. Now since I don't want the client code to be in charge of managing the `MyClass` instances, I want to add another layer to be responsible for that, so that I would have:

```
{
   t = new T();
   t.bar<choice>();
};
```

inside the function.

Ideally, I would like to be able to call this layer, let's call it `foo()`, like this:

```
foo<MyClass::Choices::One>(...);
```

Is this possible? This is what I tried and am getting errors:

```
template<typename T>
template<T::Choices choice>
void foo(){
   t = new T();
   t.bar<choice>();
};
```

Comment: Try it. Report if you run into any problems.

Comment: @RSahu well this is obviously wrong. `It gives me: error: 'T::Choices' is not a type` and `error: too many template-parameter-lists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the best you can do using the idea of traits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct choice_traits;

class MyClass{
public:
    enum Choices : int
    {
        First,
        Last
    };
    template<MyClass::Choices choice>
    void bar(...) {}
};

template <>
struct choice_traits<MyClass::Choices>
{
    using parent = MyClass;
};

template <MyClass::Choices C>
using choice_const = std::integral_constant<MyClass::Choices, C>;

template <typename C, C value>
void foo(std::integral_constant<C, value>)
{
    using T = typename choice_traits<C>::parent;

    T* t = new T();

    t->template bar<value>();
}

int main()
{
    foo(choice_const<MyClass::Choices::First>());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You need to specialize `choice_traits` for each container class that has an enum of choices. I also created a helper `choice_const` in order to avoid directly using `std::integral_constant`.

It could be improved upon if there was more information but that's as much as can be done based on your explanation.

Comment: Ha I like this.